# Why does /etc/issue show me Ubuntu and not Lubuntu?

Tags: desktop-environments

`cat /etc/issue` shows me

```
Ubuntu 13.04 \n \l
```

but I'm on Lubuntu 13.04. What is the purpose of `/etc/issue`? Also, what does `\n \l` in the output mean?

There's also `issue.net` which has just `Ubuntu 13.04`.

(I know that `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` gives me `Lubuntu`.)

Comment: Note that Lubuntu is just Ubuntu with a different set of preselected packages. You can have Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu and Xubuntu all installed at the same time. This makes it impossible to denote a single flavour in there. And `$DESKTOP_SESSION` is an environment variable that only works from within the desktop session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the man page for `issue`:

> The  file /etc/issue is a text file which contains a message or system identification to be printed before the login prompt.  It  may  contain  various @char  and  \char sequences, if supported by the getty-type program employed  on the system.

So the following `mingetty` sequences can be used...

```
Tag Description

\d  insert current day (localtime),
\l  insert line on which mingetty is running,
\m  inserts machine architecture (uname -m),
\n  inserts machine’s network node hostname (uname -n),
\o  inserts domain name,
\r  inserts operating system release (uname -r),
\t  insert current time (localtime),
\s  inserts operating system name,
\u  The current number of users which are currently logged in
\U  Same as \u but inserts "n users"
\v  Inserts operating system version (uname -v).
```

As far as `/etc/issue` goes and it showing Ubuntu: the file is not related to the desktop session and it is a text file you can manually change with `vi` or `nano`.

Could be considered a bug if you did not change it yourself but it could also be considered a user file that should be left to the user to change.

Comment: `/etc/lsb-release` will just list Ubuntu on any flavour too, by the way, for the same reason as described in [my other comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335695/why-does-etc-issue-show-me-ubuntu-and-not-lubuntu#comment427763_335695). I would also recommend against manually editing `/etc/issue`. Some scripts really depend on the specific contents. If you would edit it to `Lubuntu` several scripts checking for the OS will fail.

Comment: I've just learned that `man` isn't limited to commands :)

Comment: @gertvdijk, I won't edit those files. In general, I stay away from fiddling with system files.

Comment: @gertvdijk /etc/issue is -not- a system file. It is used to create a personal login text. If present it will never be overwritten.

Comment: Where does uname get all that information from? Is it stored somewhere?